# Why doesn't sshd care that a user doesn't own their home directory when their login has no password?

Tags: sshd

Strangest behavior I've seen in a while:

I have:

Setup a Linux user account with a password, and an ssh key.

- When this user owns their home directory, they can login with the ssh key.
- When this user does not own their home directory, `sshd` complains:

  ```
  Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /path/to/home/user/
  ```
- When I remove the Linux account password: This user may login with their ssh key while not owning their home directory.

Wat? Why does `sshd` stop caring about them owning their home directory?

Comment: Who owns the home directory? Root, or some other user?

Comment: @Gilles 
 
In this case root was the owner of their home directory, do you think root-owned-homes are treated different than mis-owned homes?

Comment: I don't know the details, but yes, it makes a difference. A restricted account with a root-owned home (so that the user can't write to their home directory) is common.

Comment: By the way, when sshd complains, there should be detailed information in the system logs. Please copy all the relevant log lines into your question.

Comment: Isn't the password-based auth routed through PAM and the key-based isn't (because it's handled by sshd itself)? In that case it could be that PAM is complaining – after all, you're about to execute an "alien" `.profile`.

Comment: Because if someone else owns the home directory, they can unlink `~/.ssh/` and replace its contents with whatever they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is little bit more complicated than you are describing (and you omit many important details to completely answer this question). But the [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_9_3_P2/auth.c#L418) is a good place to start:

- The failure is issued only if the public key authentication is performed
- The parent directories are important and they are "accepted" only if

  - the `sshd` can `stat()` it
  - the directory is owned by the logging in user OR `root` on Linux (`platform_sys_dir_uid()` takes care of that)
  - the directory is not writable by any other user (the write bit can be set only for the owner)

This basically matches your first two points, but not the third one. There will be something else in round you changed or did not notice. Turn on the debug logging on the server and investigate it (or post it to the edited question).

Comment: On my third bullet, it was root who owned their home. I used `sudo passwd -d <username>` to clear the users password to get bullet 3 to function. Does that demystify anything?

Comment: No. When the home is owned by user or root, it should just work. If not, it should not. The presence of password does not matter.

Comment: pasting the relevant permalink https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/c88a8788f9865d02b986d00405b9f0be65ad0b5a/auth.c#L418 because L524 linked above, points to something different in current version of file auth.c

Comment: @prembhaskal thanks! Updated the link. Next time you can suggest the edit directly!